# Zapier: How to send data to my Node.js web app from ScheduleOnce using Zapier

Tags: zapier

Here is my workflow:

1. Person clicks on my ScheduleOnce link and schedules a meeting
2. Upon completing the ScheduleOnce booking form, the person clicks the done button
3. When this done button is clicked the person is redirected to a Node JS web app that displays an application page. This application page needs to be auto-populated with the information from the ScheduleOnce page.

Between step 2 and 3 is where Zapier comes in. I am trying to use Zapier to capture the data from the ScheduleOnce booking, which it is. Then I am trying to use a Zap to send that data to the page the person is redirected to, to auto-populate some of the fields.

I thought using the Code Javascript functionality would work but it does not. So then I was thinking about using the StoreClient option or the API. I am just confused on how to get the flow to work to access the data and auto-populate the fields on the next redirected page.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have for the Javascript option:

```
    var store = StoreClient("Secret");
    store
        .setMany({firstName: inputData.firstName, lastName: inputData.lastName, email: inputData.email, mobilePhone: inputData.mobilePhone, otherPhone: inputData.otherPhone, businessWebsite: inputData.businessWebsite})
        .then(function() {
            return store.getMany('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'mobilePhone', 'otherPhone', 'businessWebsite');
        })
        .then(function() {
            callback();
        })
        .catch(callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. This is a cool use case and is probably possible. Something you need to remember is that Zapier is running totally separately from the user, so interaction will have to be indirect. Zapier can't redirect your user anywhere, it can just store data in response to a button push.

In your case you can skip everything after the `setMany`, since you're not trying to use the values in the zap; you just need to store them (and verify that action completed without errors).

```
var store = StoreClient("Secret");
    store
        .setMany({firstName: inputData.firstName, lastName: inputData.lastName, email: inputData.email, mobilePhone: inputData.mobilePhone, otherPhone: inputData.otherPhone, businessWebsite: inputData.businessWebsite})
        .catch(callback);
```

You'll need to solve a couple of problems:

1. **Speed**. the user will reach your landing page before the zap completes (as it has to make a couple of HTTP round trips and execute code). You'll want to play them a 3 second loading gif, or put a waiting message and allow them to refresh the destination
2. **Populating the page**. I'm not sure what the nature of the destination is (best case scenario is that it's a server you control), but something will need to make an http request to `store.zapier.com` to retrieve the stored data and surface it in the view. This is easy if
3. **Identifying the user**. You'll need some way to identify the user getting redirected to the data you stored in StoreClient. If two users fill out the form in quick succession, the second one will currently overwrite the first. Plus, it seems to be semi-sensitive data that you don't just want available to anyone on your site. To that end, you'll probably want to store all of the data as a JSON string keyed by the user's email (or something else unique). That way, when I (the user) finish the form, I'm redirected to `yoursite.com/landing?email=david@zapier.com`, the backend knows to look for (the `david@zapier.com` key in store) and can render a view with the correct info.

To that end, I'd tweak the code to the following:

```
var store = StoreClient("Secret");
    store
        .set(inputData.email, JSON.stringify({firstName: inputData.firstName, lastName: inputData.lastName, email: inputData.email, mobilePhone: inputData.mobilePhone, otherPhone: inputData.otherPhone, businessWebsite: inputData.businessWebsite}))
        .catch(callback);
```

Hope that points you in the right direction. You're working with a pretty complicated workflow, but I bet you can do it!

Comment: Great, thank you! So I have updated my Zapier code to as follows below:  

 `var customerInfo = {"firstName": inputData.firstName, "lastName": inputData.lastName, "email": inputData.email, "mobilePhone": inputData.mobilePhone, "otherPhone": inputData.otherPhone, "businessWebsite": inputData.businessWebsite};`  

 `var store = StoreClient("T5@2qaifla");`  

 `store.set(inputData.email, JSON.stringify(customerInfo)).catch(callback);` . But I continue to get an error on the Test Code by Zapier :-( Error: 
You must return a single object or array of objects.  Any ideas?

Comment: oh, sorry. You need to call `callback` somewhere (I always forget that part). so after the `set` but before the `catch`, add `.then(function(){ callback(null, {ok: true}) })` to let the runner know that you're done and everything was ok.

Comment: also if that's your real secret, you'll want to go ahead and use something different that's still a secret. 

Comment: Ah! Beautiful! It worked! And yes, my secret is actually a very secret secret. So now that that works, to access the data that is in the stored object I just use the API call store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=12345&key=firstName&key=lastName&key=email&key=modilePhone&key=otherPhone&key=businessWebsite which also appears to work. So on the button redirect, I need to set ?email=email@email.com key in the redirect url correct?

Comment: Yep, the form will need to send the info along!

Comment: Solid. Now I just need to figure out if ScheduleOnce can send entered data on that form as a URL parameter. Once that gets figured out, do I search through the store item for that matching email and access that object to retrieve the data?

Comment: Yep! I don't know anything about ScheduleOnce but hopefully that part works. And yeah, then it's store.get(email) to get the data if it exists. I'd strip the email before storing it, since people tend to have trailing spaces and you need an exact match.